# link show only 0.5 sec then hide in juqery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, show

i write this code in my site. And the hidden function well perform but when i click on link to show, then it show only for 0.5 sec and then hide this. Please tell me where i mistake.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("div").click(function(){
            $("a:contains('Show content')" ).hide("none");
        });

        $("div:contains('Show map')").click(function(){
            $("a:contains('Show content')" ).show("none");
        });

    });
</script>

<a href="#"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btm-zindex " id="Show_cont"  >Show content</a>

<div class="col-md-12 profile profile_closed btn1" id="profile"></div>
```

Comment: '<a href="#"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btm-zindex " id="Show_cont"  >Show content</a>

<div class="col-md-12 profile profile_closed btn1" id="profile"></div>'

Comment: Please add this info to your post instead of in the comments. It's hard to see what it is supposed to mean. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This `$("div").click(` is wrong because you do not have a `div` with that content, your element is an `a` tag, but even using that is unadvised (its not likely to be the *only* `a` tag)

You have an ID on the element so you might want something like this:

```js
  $('#Show_cont').click(function() {
    $("a:contains(Show content)").hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btm-zindex " id="Show_cont">Show content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you click on `div:contains('Show map')` run both show and hide function Because both function react to click the div.

for fix it,give on `class` to tag `div'.

```
<div class="hid">

     <a href="#">Show content</a>

</div>
```

and change jQuery like this :

```
$(".hid").click(function(){

            $("a:contains('Show content')" ).hide("none");
 })
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            .hid a{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="hid">
            <a href="#"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btm-zindex " id="Show_cont"  >Show content</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 profile profile_closed btn1" id="profile">Show map</div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".hid").click(function(){
            $("a:contains('Show content')" ).hide("none");
        });

        $("div:contains('Show map')").click(function(){
            $("a:contains('Show content')" ).show();
        });

    });             

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```